# Parámetro llega como undefined al pasarlo de un componente a otro

Tags: reactjs

Estoy teniendo un problema cuyo origen desconozco pero que no alcanzo a resolver. Al pasarle un parámetro (un array en este caso) a un componente, me llega como `undefined`.

He creado un array de objetos de la siguiente forma:

```
const taquillas = [
  {
    type: 'slider',
    title: 'Número de puertas',
    image: 'http://…/imagen.jpg',
    items: [
      {title: 'una puerta', image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080'},
      {title: 'una puerta', image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080'},
      {title: 'una puerta', image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080'},
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'medidas',
    type: 'measures',
    altura: [],
    anchura: [],
    items: [],
  },
  {
    title: 'colores',
    type: 'colors',
    cuerpo: ['#daf34', '#423k2'],
    puertas: ['#fff', '#f00'],
    items: [],
  },
];
```

Y en el mismo fichero lo recorro y se lo envío a otro componente:

```
{
            taquillas.map((item, index) => (
              <>
                {console.log(item.items)}
                <OptionSlider
                  description={item.description}
                  detailType={item.type}
                  itemsDetails={item.items}
                  key={index}
                  title={item.title}
                />
              </>
            ))
          }
```

El componente de destino recibe todos los parámetros correctamente, a excepción de `itemsDetails`.

```
const OptionSlider = ({description, detailType, itemDetails, title}) => (
  <section>
/* aquí ya llega como undefined */
  </section>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás definiendo `itemsDetails={item.items}` como `itemsDetails` (fíjate en la "s" de items) y en la función `OptionSlider` defines `itemDetails` (sin la "s").

Comment: No lo veía. ¡Gracias!